# Angular orderBy does not seem to order by

Tags: angularjs

a quick question - I'm probably missing something obvious, but I have the following code:

```
dateList = $filter('orderBy')(dateList) // dateList is a list of strings

console.log(dateList)
```

The output logged to console follows:

```
["2014-02-12", "2014-01-22", "2013-10-17", ... "2013-01-01", "2014-03-27", "2014-02-08", "2014-01-18", "2012-12-12"]
```

I notice that the final few dates are not sorted (although the vast majority are).

Can you see where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
I have looked at the answer to the other question, and changing to the following code made no difference:

`dateList = $filter('orderBy')(dateList, "toString()")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do orderby with angularJS for string array not object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064106/how-to-do-orderby-with-angularjs-for-string-array-not-object-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a pure JS solution, as Angular is just JS.

```
dateList.sort();
```

Comment: Although this doesn't really explain the angular behaviour, I am marking as an answer, as it works just fine

Comment: Agreed - I tried for a while to get this to work the Angular way, then I thought why not just pure good old fashion JS?